# Maven Code Gen and Compile Plugin: Java Compiler : Classpath Issues

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-plugin, java-compiler-api

I'm working on a maven plugin which will generate code and compile it. When I'm using a plugin source code via a test in Eclipse, things work great. Without even setting the classpath in the JavaCompiler ( Javax.tools ).

But, when I package it and run it as a maven plugin. The compilation of the generated code fails with not able to find the referenced classes like Jackson annotations.

I tried

1. Tried setting classpath option on the JavaCompiler pointing to the local maven repo, it still could not find the necessary classes.
2. setting the classpath to jackson annotation jar and commons lang(which are needed by my generated code), then things seems to work OKAY.

Working code:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
            DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
            StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler
                    .getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
            Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager
                    .getJavaFileObjects(classDirectory.listFiles());
            List<String> optionsList = new ArrayList<String>();

            System.setProperty("java.class.path", "/Users/vayipalayamchand/.m2/maven.repo:../..");
            optionsList.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath","/Users/vayipalayamchand/.m2/maven.repo/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.1.0/jackson-annotations-2.1.0.jar:/Users/vayipalayamchand/.m2/maven.repo/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar:../../:$CLASSPATH"));
            JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null,
                    fileManager, diagnostics, optionsList , null, compilationUnits);
            boolean isSuccess = task.call();
            fileManager.close();
```

Problems with this setting classpath with paths to the jar approach:

- Its not clean. Users of the plugin need to specify the location of these jars ( not even counting this as a option.

What is a better way to make sure, my JavaCompiler can find the necessary dependencies to compile the generated code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok generation is ok but why compiling yourself and not let the maven-compiler-plugin do the work?

Comment: Do you declare the plugin dependencies with the correct scope (runtime/compile) in the plugin's pom file?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm compiling because I want to instantiate it to create some sample JSON.

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov, I have specified the dependencies as compile time. Let me try to make it runtime dependencies.